# How can I make it so that the mousemove event works in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a course on Visual Studio right now and I'm at a point where I have no idea what I'm doing. this is my current code; it's supposed to make the labels have the location of where the mouse is in the picture box of my form.

```
private void picShowPicture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
lblX.Text = "X: " & e.X;
lblY.Text = "Y: " & e.Y;
```

Comment: Okay. Looks like a good start. Does it compile? Did you register this handler with your pictureBox? Did you set a breakpoint to make sure it gets called?

Comment: This might not be the only problem but you need to use `+` instead of `&`. Also, the event handler is missing curly brackets. I'm not sure if that's the case in your real code. If you wrote this manually (or copied it from somewhere), you probably haven't registered the event handler as nvoigt suggested above.

Comment: For the record, `&` is the string concatenation operator in VB. In C#, `+` is the concatenation operator and `&` is the bitwise AND operator and the non-short-circuiting Boolean AND operator.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably that should be like so:

```cs
private void picShowPicture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lblX.Text = "X: " + e.X;
    lblY.Text = "Y: " + e.Y;
}
```

Note that that code appears to be handling an event of a `PictureBox` control, so it will only work if the mouse pointer is over that control and it will display the position relative to that control.

You also have to have registered the event handler, which won't happen automatically if you copied that code from somewhere.

Comment: you're literally my saviour! it worked as it should, so thank you all so very much for the help!